# Broken link to SE's main page on the side bar

Tags: bug

The side bar has a link to "more site stats" on SE's main page:

[image]

The link seems to be broken. It points to https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#opensource, which after a couple of seconds just refreshes to the site list. I'm guessing it's supposed to expand the site's box on the main page, like this:

[image]

Can we please get this fixed?